# Remove self-closing tags (e.g. />) in an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlwriter

In an XmlDocument, either when writing and modify later, is it possible to remove the self-closing tags (i.e.  `/>`) for a certain element.

For example: change

- `<img />` or `<img></img>` to `<img>`.
- `<br />` to `<br>`.

Why you ask? I'm trying to conform to the *HTML for Word 2007* schema; the resulting HTML will be displayed in *Microsoft Outlook 2007* or later.

After reading another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107909/how-to-remove-closing-tag-of-an-xmldocument-in-c-net-1-1), I tried the setting the `IsEmpty` property to `false` like so.

```cs
var imgElements = finalHtmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()=\"img\"]").OfType<XmlElement>();
foreach (var element in imgElements)
{
    element.IsEmpty = false;
}
```

However that resulted in `<img />` becoming `<img></img>`. Also, as a hack I also tried changing the `OuterXml` property directly however that doesn't work (didn't expect it to).

**Question**

Can you remove the self-closing tags from `XmlDocument`? I *honestly* do not think there is, as it would then be invalid xml (no closing tag), however thought I would throw the question out the community.

**Update:**

I ended up fixing the HTML string after exporting from the `XmlDocument` using a regular expression (written in the wonderful [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)).

```
    var fixHtmlRegex = new Regex("<(?<tag>meta|img|br)(?<attributes>.*?)/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    return fixHtmlRegex.Replace(htmlStringBuilder.ToString(), "<$1$2>");
```

It cleared many errors from the validation pass and allow me to focus on the real compatibility problems.

Comment: Using `<img />` and `<br />` works fine in Office 2007/10, is there another reason for converting to HTML4 style tags?

Comment: looking at the answers you know, you can't do it through XMLDocument. But if you really want this, why don't you try creating a text file with string operations on XML, that way you can achieve your task

Comment: @Matthew: Yes they do; the only reason was to validate against [HTML for Word 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28office.12%29.aspx) schema so that at a later point the conversion could be unit tested.

Comment: I believe http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ supports saving as HTML4 compliance, which will give you the `<img>` short tag.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. ... What is your experience using the HTML Agility pack? A quick glance at the project reveals little documentation or examples.

Comment: It works well, it's very similar to parsing XML, you can use `XPATH` selectors, more flexible than the XML parser (in terms of modifying HTML).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: it's not possible simply because it's invalid (or rather, *not well-formed*) XML. Empty elements in XML **must** be closed, be it with the shortcut syntax `/>` or with an immediate closing tag.

Comment: Strange that the `XmlWriter` will not let you write invalid XML.

Comment: He would have to use the `InvalidXmlWriter` class for that.

Comment: As I thought. Thanks for the quick reply. @Matthew was correct in his comment on the question; both tags work fine in Office 2007/10.

Answer (score 1):

Both HTML and XML are applications of SGML. While HTML and SGML allow unclosed tags like `<br>`, XML does not.

Answer (score 1):

A bit embarrassed by my answer, but it worked for what I needed.  After you have a complete xml document you can string manipulate it to clean it up...

```
private string RemoveSelfClosingTags(string xml)
    {
        char[] seperators = { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' };

        int prevIndex = -1;
        while (xml.Contains("/>"))
        {
            int selfCloseIndex = xml.IndexOf("/>");
            if (prevIndex == selfCloseIndex)
                return xml; // we are in a loop...

            prevIndex = selfCloseIndex;

            int tagStartIndex = -1;

            string tag = "";

            //really? no backwards indexof?
            for (int i = selfCloseIndex; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (xml[i] == '<')
                {
                    tagStartIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }


            int tagEndIndex = xml.IndexOfAny(seperators, tagStartIndex);
            int tagLength = tagEndIndex - tagStartIndex;
            tag = xml.Substring(tagStartIndex + 1, tagLength - 1);


            xml = xml.Substring(0, selfCloseIndex) + "></" + tag + ">" + xml.Substring(selfCloseIndex + 2);
        }

        return xml;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` would not be valid XML, so no, you can't do this.